# Automation studio activity fails

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I have an automation that includes several steps.
If an error occurs in the first step, does it go to the second step or does it stop?

I can't try automation because I don't have the platform, it's for training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the automation to continue to the next steps, each of the activities in the preceeding steps need to finish successfuly (not error or time out).

You can also use [Verification activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_verification_activity.htm&type=5) to stop the automation prematurely if a data extension which you would expect containing records, is empty. This can be used to avoid triggering a journey or Email Send activity with an empty sendable data extension.

Comment: Hi Lukas, i have a question. If I use Verification activity, and  it stop my automation, 
Since I have scheduled all days, the next day the automation will be blocked if I don't correct the error?

Comment: Hi @MaryjON - it is only the current execution which will stopped. Any future scheduled automation runs will still be executed. Of course if the Verification Activity still experiences same issue as in the last run, it will stop the automation again.